# Xamarin Forms Error "invalid resource directory name: /Path/res Icon "res Icon"

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Yesterday everything worked fine and the app get build successfully.

But when I want to build the app now, I always get the following error:

> invalid resource directory name:
>   /path/to/project.android/obj/Debug/Ip/26/jl/res Icon "res Icon".

Does somebody know how to fix that?

Comment: Improved formatting.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a space character in the name of your `resource file` or `directory` which is not allowed:

"File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore"

Answer (score 0):

### I don't know how but this fixed my problem.

Use incremental Android packaging system (aapt2).

[image]